# How to define anonymous types in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, anonymous-types

I'm writing a C++/CLI class, and I need to have something like this:

```
System::Object^ person = gcnew { firstName = "John", lastName = "Smith" };
```

Here is what I found for C#:
[MSDN - Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx)

Does anyone have an example for C++/CLI, if it is at all possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything on anonymous types, so I just defined a class for it really quick:

```
public ref class Person { String^ firstName; String^ lastName; }
```

and then just used it instead of the Object:

```
Person^ person = gcnew Person();
person->firstName = "John";
person->lastName = "Smith";
```

Although it gives some advantages over anonymous types such as IntelliSense, it would still be interesting to know if anonymous types are supported in C++/CLI.